# jqote returning undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqote

I'm trying to update an HTML table with new data pulled in via json and using jQote.

I have a fairly simple jqote template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <![CDATA[
        <tr>
            <td><%= this.customer_id %></td>
            <td><%= this.campaign_id %></td>
            <td><%= this.cname %></td>
            <td><%= this.create_date %></td>
            <td><%= this.phone %></td>
            <td><%= this.sname %></td>
            <td><%= this.reminder %></td>
            <td><%= this.appt_date %></td>
            <td><%= this.note %></td>
            <td><%= this.unread %></td>
        </tr>
    ]]>
</script>
```

And here's my JSON:

```
[{
    "customer_id": "2081",
    "campaign_id": "812",
    "cname": "Jeff",
    "create_date": "3 days ",
    "phone": "1111111111",
    "sname": "Massage Appointment",
    "reminder": "0",
    "appt_date": "0",
    "note": "",
    "unread": "2"
}]
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url/for/json/return',
    dataType: 'text/json',
    data: 'huh',
    success: function(jsondata){
        row = $('#template').jqote(jsondata);
        $('#customers > tbody').html(row); 
    },
 }
});
```

The ajax request runs fine and jsondata has the proper data stored inside, but my jQote tags are all returning undefined. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff, the JSON `data` variable fetched via POST is merely a string. You need to parse it with [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) prior to handing it over to jQote. Another possibility - as you have already figured out yourself - is to use jQuery's `$.getJSON` method which parses the response automatically.

In case you are making use of jQote2 and jQuery 1.4.1 or above you should rewrite your script like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url/for/json/return',
    dataType: 'text/json',
    data: 'huh',
    success: function(jsondata){
        var data = $.parseJSON(jsondata);
        // Call the "substitute HTML" convenience method
        $('#customers > tbody').jqotesub('#template', data);
    }
});
```

For a description of `$().jqotesub` have a look at the [jQote2 reference](http://aefxx.com/api/jqote2-reference/#jqotesub).

Comment: Thank you so much! Odd that the examples I've seen using jQote in this way didn't explain the need to use parseJSON.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a working example of what I needed to do. Here is the new jQuery I used:

```
var jsondata = $.getJSON('/url/for/json/return/ajax/', function(data) {
    row = $('#template').jqote(data);
    $('#customers > tbody').html(row);
});
```